# How should normal 'pro' strategies be modified for lower-level games?

Tags: league-of-legends

In a pro game, typically lanes are simply farming passively for at least the first few levels, but at my lower bracket, this usually doesn't happen. I had been using pro guides, based on that style of play, and hadn't been having much luck against the very aggressive lane opponents. Typically, I found my games being decided by deaths in lane within the first ten minutes, and I was usually losing those ten minutes.

In the last few days I've started running much more aggressive, front-loaded builds and rune setups, and immediately went from a roughly 60-40 win ratio to 80-20 for the next twenty games. My question, then, is what other ways can I adapt my play at low ratings as opposed to pro-level strategies to win those lower level games? Presumably the meta is the meta for a reason, so how can I punish my opponents for using different strategies?

Comment: Ability to easily communicate with your teammates is probably the biggest difference. Taking advantage of this is how you're going to get ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You cant "punish" a team that uses a different strategy just because its "different" Any strategy can work well if executed perfectly.

### At low ELO there is a few things that are forgoten/not done.

- Low ELO players seem to forget about objectives like dragon, buffs, and baron.
- More focused on kills(greedy) rather than farm, this can make them be over-confident and make mistakes which can lead to them being out of position which you can take advantage of.
- Lack of focus in team fights and bad positioning
- No/lack of warding on the map.

Also if a team is choosing a comp that you have not seen before, look at the champs that are being used, do they excel at; Pushing towers? Strong early game or late? AOE based or single targeted? Anti-carry? etc etc.

It all lies down to you and your team, pick up on mistakes, see weakness's and abuse it.

Answer (score 0):

In the lowest of rated games, running a jungler when they do not can easily win you the game. Just make sure that you gank the guy who is 1v2's lane a lot (Or duo que with someone who can play a solo v 2 champion). At lower elos, they have NO map awareness, and just complain about "mia calls" all day. So just take advantage of that. Even if you are laning, just push out the lane, and head mid. 90% chance hes still chilling in lane, doesn't even know what you are doing.

Take advantage of the fact that they do not buy wards, and don't watch them if they do. Place wards in the river and their jungle. You can easily pick off the trist that goes for red buff, because they still think their jungle is safe.

Also. Early dragons, or even dragon at all, are almost never contested. Most of them forget that guy even exists. Dou que with an excellent jungle and take fast dragons, or even barons.